# How to grep logs with line break

Tags: grep

I have a log file with the following structure, some logs will contain line breaks like `[query-id=123]`

```
[query-id=123] contentA:
 1. content
 2. content
 3. content
[query-id=124] contentC
[query-id=123] contentB:
 1. contentB
 2. contentB
```

So what I want to grep is the whole content of the log `[query-id=123]`, but if I grep `query-id=123`, I can only get the lines with header `[query-id=123] contentA:` and `[query-id=123] contentB:`, the lines following the lines with header would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

`pcregrep` has a `M`ulitline mode which you could use for that:

```
$ pcregrep -M 'query-id=123\b.*(\n\h.*)*' your-file
[query-id=123] contentA:
 1. content
 2. content
 3. content
[query-id=123] contentB:
 1. contentB
 2. contentB
```

`\h` is for `h`orizontal space character. Also note the `\b` for word `b`oundary without which `query-id=123` would also match in `query-id=1234`. Or you could be more explicit and grep for `[query-id=123]` at the start of a line:

```
pcregrep -M '^\[query-id=123\].*(\n\h.*)*' your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -v SECTION='\\[query-id=123\\]' '/^\[query-id/ {HEADER=$0} HEADER ~ SECTION {print $0}' file          
[query-id=123] contentA:
 1. content
 2. content
 3. content
[query-id=123] contentB:
 1. contentB
 2. contentB
```

More readable:

```
awk -v SECTION='\\[query-id=123\\]' '
/^\[query-id/ {
  HEADER=$0
}
HEADER ~ SECTION {
  print $0
}' file
```

Or, if the format of the header is always `[query-id=<NUMBER>]`, you can provide only the number as the `SECTION` variable instead of the entire header:

```
$ awk -v SECTION='123' 'BEGIN {PATTERN=sprintf("^\\[query-id=%s\\]", SECTION)} /^\[query-id/ {HEADER=$0} HEADER ~ PATTERN {print $0}' file
[query-id=123] contentA:
 1. content
 2. content
 3. content
[query-id=123] contentB:
 1. contentB
 2. contentB
```

Readable:

```
awk -v SECTION='123' '
BEGIN {
  PATTERN=sprintf("^\\[query-id=%s\\]", SECTION)
}

/^\[query-id/ {
  HEADER=$0
}

HEADER ~ PATTERN {
  print $0
}' file
```